# How to access a variable from a different class in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, coordinates, instance-variables

I have a latitude and a longitude saved in two different double type variables in class1, which I have obtained by grabbing the coordinates from a dropped pin on a map.

I then have a different class2 where I calculate the times the sun sets and rises using the current time and the coordinates.

In class3 I then create an instance of the class2 method that calculates the times for me. I have no problem using this when the latitude and longitude used are the one of the user's current location using location services, but when it comes to specifying that I need the coordinates saved in those class1 variables, it keeps returning 0.0000 for both coordinates.

So basically, how do I tell my class3 that I want to use the doubles saved in class1? I imagine it's something along the lines of:

```
Class1 *instance = [[Class1 alloc] init];

instance.savedLatitude = myNewLat;
```

but this initialises myNewLat to 0.000 and I need them to be the ones grabbed from that previously dropped pin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are more things to get this right.

1) In class1 import the core location framework.
    @import CoreLocation;

2) In class1 declare a property called let say "coordinates"

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;

Note that the property is a structure data type (so no pointer star *), but this is the one that should be used for coordinates, there is no point reinventing the wheel unless you have a better wheel. When you have an instance of class 1, make sure you save the coordinates into the property the right way.

3) If you want to access the coordinates of some class1 instance, then you have to have a reference to that concrete instance. What you do in here

```
Class1 *instance = [[Class1 alloc] init];
instance.savedLatitude = myNewLat;
```

is you are creating a new instance which has its coordinates as zero, because it's a new instance and this is how it is initialized by default.
You can get the reference to that concrete class1 instance by passing it along to other objects via some configuration method or some custom initialiser.

You need to understand the difference between Class as abstract blueprint/recipe and concrete instance(s) of Class. Of course you are getting zero for coordinates when it is NOT the instance that has the co-ordinates you were expecting. It is different, new one.

Also do not confuse instance variables and getters and server for properties. 
Instance variables are by convention internal to the instance, properties are the public interface for them (usually).

Answer (score -1):

This is my very first post so please go gentle on me everyone :)
I am an experienced old-boy 'progressive' C programmer and have only recently started studying OOPS programming, using JAVA, but I hope my comment helps.

If you able to pass the instance of Class1 to Class3, setup getters/setters in Class1, than have Class3 simply 'get' the values of lat/lon from Class1.

Not sure if this exactly relates to objective C but I suspect the rationale behind it maybe what you are searching for?

Comment: I am indeed looking for the equivalent of a get method in Java I believe, but I thought the way to do that was creating that instance of the class and then calling those variables but when I assign this to a new variable I get 0, so I am obviously not retrieving the values correctly